# does DBCC ShrinkDatabase do a Reorganize of files?

Tags: dbcc

does DBCC ShrinkDatabase doa  Reorganize of files?

Basically does it mimic the same process as if i checked Reorganize in the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, actually it is notoriously bad for fragmenting the data. You should do a re-org after the shrink is complete.

FROM [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx):

> A shrink operation does not preserve
>   the fragmentation state of indexes in
>   the database, and generally increases
>   fragmentation to a degree. This is
>   another reason not to repeatedly
>   shrink the database.

Comment: +1 http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Shrink is file shrinkage and does [DBCC SHRINKDATABASE or DBCC SHRINKFILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)
- Reorganise is index maintenance, invoked by [ALTER INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx)

No overlap except in some *rare* cases where you have heaps (tables without clustered indexes)